# Questions Regarding Installing Theano

Tags: theano

I am installing theano on my Mac OSX using command

pip install Theano

It tries to install all the related packages like numpy , scipy along with it .

It is using Python 2.7 for installation : .

I ran into errors during installation

Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1

DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.

Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/sumanth/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)

File "/Users/sumanth/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run

My whole objective is, i want all these packages to be installed using python 3, the whole package has to work with python 3. I have installed numpy separately in the past,i want to just ignore it and do a whole new installation over Python 3.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Sumanth

Comment: Could you give more info about your setup? (OS, version of python installed .etc). Also, could you try using `pip3 install theano` ?

Comment: Gokul , my os version OS X 10.10.5 , i installed python 3 , but always system takes python2.7 as default , which is the default .

Comment: Do i need to install pip3  ?

Comment: type `pip --version` if it prints out something like `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` then `pip` is linked with `python 2` and you need to install `pip3`. If you get `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` then it is linked with `python 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

command pip3 install theano helped

installed perfectly , Thanks a lot Gokul

Comment: Need one more help related this, there are some projects which are written in python2.x, need to configure numpy, theano for the python2.x version, running into same installation problems as mentioned earlier. Any help is appreciated.